# How to hide multiple buttons using loop in javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function hide_input_items()
{

        var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');

          for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) 
          {

            if(inputs[i].type=='text') 
            {
              inputs[i].disabled=1;
            }
        }
            var updates  =  document.getElementById('update');
            var cancels  =  document.getElementById('cancel');
        for(var j=1;j<up;j++)
        {

            updates[j].style.visibility = "hidden";
             cancels[j].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }        
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$counter=0;
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
{
$counter++;
$name= "name".$counter;
$update="update".$counter;
$cancel="cancel".$counter;
$edit= "edit".$counter;
?>


<input type="text" name="name" id="name" id="<?php echo $name;?>" value="hi" />
<input type="button" name="edit"  id="name" id="<?php echo $edit;?>" value="Edit" onclick="focuse('<?php //echo $id.",".$update.",".$cancel.",".$edit;?>')"/>
<input type="button" name="update"  id="name" id="<?php echo $update;?>" value="Update" onclick="display('<?php //echo $cancel;?>');"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" id="name" id="<?php echo $cancel;?>" value="Cancel" onclick="show()"/>

<br />



<?php

}?>
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="hide_all();" value="Hide all" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to hide update and cancel button on page load but it does not working when i add second loop in page load function then then upper loop is also disable.Here above is my complete code please do give some suggestion if do you have. Thanks.

Comment: I am showing input field and edit,update,cancel buttons with php loop 9 times

Comment: Why do you need loop to hide elements?? You could use a specific class for text inputs & updates accordingly.

Comment: I'd create a <form> and I'll made a loop like `for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)` and I'll loop through all elements like `if(document.forms[0].type=='text') document.forms[0].disabled=1`. Do the same with your button